# Symfony2 form.error field not working

Tags: forms, symfony, view

i got a problem. I created a form class and set some asserts to my entitiy.

But now i want to render the errors.
I got the form_erros for global erros, but not for the fields.

Here the code:

Controller

```
public function addAction(Request $request){
    $news = new news();
    $form = $this->createForm(new NewsType(),$news);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
    echo "YEPP";
    }

    return array( 'form' => $form->createView() );
}
```

Formclass

```
$builder
        ->add('unpublic','checkbox',array(
                'required' => false))
        ->add('unactive','checkbox',array(
                'required' => false))
        ->add('untitle','text',array(
                'required' => true))
```

View

```
<div class="form-group">
   {{ form_label(form.untitle,'Titel*',{ 'label_attr': {'class': 'col-sm-2  control-label'}}) }}
    <strong>{{ form_errors(form.untitle) }}</strong>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    {{ form_widget(form.untitle, {'attr': {'class' : 'form-control'} })  }}
    {{ form_errors(form.untitle) }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Entity

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="UNTITLE", type="string", length=255)
 * 
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Type("Text")
 *
 */
private $UNTITLE;
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

As you said, with `{{ form_errors(form) }}` that displays global form errors, not individual fields.

If you want individual field errors to be accessible via {{ form_errors(form) }}, you need to enable the option [`error_bubbling => true`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/text.html#error-bubbling) for each single field in your form.

Others solutions :

- render each field's error individually `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}`
- `{{ form_row(form.name) }}` for render the label, widget and errors together.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hey Thanks for your help. Isn't error_bubbling default = true?

Comment: I've tried 

->add('untitle','text',array(
     'error_bubbling' => true,
     'required' => true))
   ->add('untext','textarea',array(
     'error_bubbling' => true,
     'required' => true))
   ->add('unimage','file')
   ->add('undate','date',array(
     'widget' => 'single_text',
     'format' => 'dd.MM.yyyy',
     'error_bubbling' => true,


But its not working :(

Answer (score 0):

As zilongqiu said, u should show field's error individually with `{{ form_errors(form.name) }}`

If you want to access to field's error via the global form you can check this link : http://blog.lyrixx.info/2013/01/31/symfony2-snippet-to-render-all-form-error.html

cya.

Comment: The Problem is, it doesn't work. As you can see in the script i'm trying to use this ( {{ form_errors(form.untitle) }} ) But there is no output for it